# experimental::optional "nullopt_t" naming rationale

Tags: c++, boost, option-type

The `boost::optional` C++ library has 'no value' indicated by `boost::none`, which is a well-chosen name as code like

```
f(..., optional<T> default_argument = boost::none)
```

or

```
f(..., optional<T> default_argument = none)
```

is very readable -- the intent is clearly communicated to the reader. It's also similar to the 'no value' provided in standard classes in other languages. This Boost library was absorbed into the standard as `std::experimental::optional`, but `none` was renamed to the inscrutable `nullopt_t`. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Probably to stay consistent with other type naming practices.  The actual value is `nullopt` and it is of type `nullopt_t`.  Just like `nullptr` is a value of type `nullptr_t`.

Comment: `nullopt` is also specific to `optional<T>`, whereas `none` could apply to anything. It's an interesting problem for the standardisation of `expected<T, E>` where `expected<T, nullopt_t>` is explicitly supposed to be semantically equivalent to `optional<T>`.

Comment: @NiallDouglas That's what namespaces are for...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Funnily, it turned out to be easier to standardize `boost::optional` than to standardize `boost::none`. `boost::none`, while it serves its purpose of initializing `boost::optional`s, it doesn't have well-defined semantics.

A good well-behaved value-semantic alternative to `void` is useful, but requires a lot of questions to be answered. Should it have `operator<` and be an Ordered type? Should it be inter-convertibe with `nullptr`? Comparable with `nullptr`? I did not want these questions to impede the adoption of `boost::optional`, so we agreed on a compromise. For now, go with `nullopt` whose only purpose is to initialize `optional` objects. Add a well-behaved `none` later. And indeed a work on 'prefect' `none` is in progress. [See here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0196r2.pdf).

Comment: Very glad to hear about work on `none`.  `nullopt` _really_ hurts readability.

And, more importantly: thank you for your work on this!